# What "IVI" from "IVI Translation" stands for?

Tags: ipv6, ipv6-transition

In several documents in the context of IPv4/IPv6 transition I see these three letters "IVI" that seems to be an acronym, but I was unable to find what it means or suppose to refer.

Maybe is it a reference to something in language different than english?  Ip Versus Ip?  Any thoughts?

Some references:

- [IVI Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IVI_Translation) at Wikipedia
- [RFC6219](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6219)
- [IVI website](http://www.ivi2.org/) maintained by [China Education and Research Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CERNET)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> This document presents the CERNET IVI translation design and
> deployment for the IPv4/IPv6 coexistence and transition.  In Roman
> numerals, the "IV" stands for 4, and "VI" stands for 6, so "IVI"
> stands for the IPv4/IPv6 translation.
> ```

[RFC 6219 Sec 1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6219#section-1)

So (4) IV plus (6) VI == I[VV]I with the duplicate "V" removed.

Comment: Shame on me. It was in the first paragraph! Anyway, thank you so much.